# clear string in a column for specific rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

i got a table which looks like this:

```
| col1 | ... | colx |
---------------------
|  1   | ... | dfd  |
|  1   | ... | ajd  |
|  1   | ... | aad  |
|  2   | ... | azd  |
|  2   | ... | iod  |
|  3   | ... | asd  |
|  3   | ... | aod  |
|  3   | ... | wsd  |
|  3   | ... | asi  |
```

i want to update the table (or create a new table), so it looks like this:

```
| col1 | ... | colx |
---------------------
|  1   | ... | dfd  |
|      | ... | ajd  |
|      | ... | aad  |
|  2   | ... | azd  |
|      | ... | iod  |
|  3   | ... | asd  |
|      | ... | aod  |
|      | ... | wsd  |
|      | ... | asi  |
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Why would you want to destroy usable data for a presentation layer item?  Besides, without a sequence how would one determine the "first" record?

Comment: i would like to create a crystal report based on that. unfortunately crystal can't do this, so i'd like to do it in sql....

Comment: @jimmmmyjooo This is fully possible just let me think

Comment: `This is fully possible` just `determine the "first" record` for each `col1`

Comment: i made a report based on a stored procedure, which returns the mentioned table... if it works with cr, please give me a little more details @OtoShavadze

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.First add a new identity column to your table so we can order and update duplicate duplicate values to null:

```
alter table yourtable
add newcol int identity
```

2. If you want to update duplicate values in col1 to null then:

```
update yourtable
set col1 = null
where newcol not in (select min(newcol) from yourtable group by col1)
```

3.See your result:

```
select
     *
from
     yourtable
order by
     newcol asc
```

You can not drop the identity column that was created but then you will loose your order..

**If you don't want to update anything and just need a query**

1.All you need is the following query AFTER you have created a new identity column on your table

```
select
     *
from
     yourtable
where
     newcol in (select min(newcol) from yourtable group by col1)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

```
Select col1 = case when RN=1 then concat('',col1) else '' end
      ,other
      ,colx
  From (
            Select *
                  ,RN = Row_Number() over (Partition By col1 order by colx) 
             From YourTable
       ) A
 Order by A.Col1,RN
```

**Returns**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
(
COL1 int,
COLX nvarchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO @MyTable(COL1,COLX)

VALUES
( 1  ,'dfd'),
( 1  ,'ajd'),
( 1  ,'aad'),
( 2  ,'azd'),
( 2  ,'iod'),
( 3  ,'asd'),
( 3  ,'aod'),
( 3  ,'wsd'),
( 3  ,'asi')

select ISNULL(newcol,'')as col1,COLX from (
Select COLX,cast(Case when rn = 1 then COL1  else null end as nvarchar(50)) 
as NewCOL from (
Select * ,Row_number() over(Partition by col1 order by col1 ) as rn from 
@MyTable
)x
)y
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: This is somewhat like what you pasted - If you need order you just order by colx instead of col1